# ASP .NET Razorpage Appdbcontext returns null for FK Object

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, dbcontext

I have `POST` method that looks like

```
A a = _context.A.Find(AId);
B b= _context.B.Find(BId);
C.A = a;
C.B = b;
_context.C.Add(C);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And debugger shows that it's good. Object `C` contains those attributes `a` and `b`. But later I do `GET` method for this `C` objects and debugger shows both `C.A = null` and `C.B = null`. Can you help me with that?
P.s in database it saves after `POST` method all corectly with `ForeignKeys`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the relationship between your classes is as follows.

```
public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? CID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? CID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class C
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}
```

The ForeignKeys `CID` should be a `nullable` type.

Then re-migrate to generate the correct table relationship.

Comment: It doesn't work. Look, I have `C` object with not nullable attributes `B` and `A`. On `POST` method it works perfectly. On `GET` from `DbContext` it returns me `C` instance with nullable `A` and `B` attributes. Can I configure this?